# Chrome Extension performance optimization?

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-chrome-extension

If I'm not mistaken, Chrome Extension files are loaded from the client's computer, therefore they are loaded very quickly?

Would it be worth combining all my JavaScript files (there are about 10 for a content script) and compile them with the Google Closure compiler?

Would I see a large performance benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Closure compiler results in, essentially, 2 things:

1. Smaller code
2. Optimized code

Smaller code advantage is not as much relevant in case of resources loaded locally. It might speed up parse time, it might lessen memory requirements, but compared to network transfer time the results will be barely noticeable (and by "noticeable" I mean "measurable" here).

As for optimized code..

- If your code is small, not very complex, and not terribly inefficient, you might see very small benefits, but again, they would be measurable, but not noticeable.
- If your code is large and complex, you might see some benefits, but it's highly dependent on *which way* it is inefficient.
- If your code is *conceptually* bad, no optimizing compiler can help. Optimizations only help with certain implementation inefficiencies, not with bad algorithms.

Also note that it will make debugging a pain. It's not simply a minifier, <s>I don't imagine that source maps would work with it</s>. Nevermind, source maps do work, but it's an additional hoop to jump through.

Bottom line: it doesn't hurt to try, but don't expect *large* benefits, and if your content scripts behave in a way that *requires* to improve performance, you probably need to redo them differently.

Comment: that was the most concise and helpful answer I've gotten from SO! thanks :D I think I broke things up a little too much thinking this is a back-end application, I'll work on fixing that!